# How to align JLabel to the left of the JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, flowlayout

I want to align my JLabel to the left.

```
    String lText = "<html><b><font color = white face = comic sans ms size = 20>mybook</font></b></html>";
    JLabel label = new JLabel(lText);
    label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(25,0,25,500));
```

I tried to do it using EmptyBorder but it isnt aligning properly. I am using FlowLayout

Answer (score 15):

`FlowLayout` uses `CENTER` alignment by default. Try using `LEFT` alignment for your `JLabel` `JPanel` container

```
myJPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
```

Comment: This align the whole panel to the left. I just want to align my label on the left.

Comment: @ArchitVerma : `Put the JLabel` on a `JPanel` with as suggested in the answer, and keep this new `JPanel` in place of the present position of your `JLabel` :-) Won't that do ?

Comment: I.e. you will need to use nested containers using if using `FlowLayout`

Answer (score 4):

You might wish to set the JLabel's horizontalAlignment property. One way is via its constructor. Try:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(lText, SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

This can also be done via the expected setter method:

```
label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

Comment: This will only align the text inside the border of the label, not how the label is aligned in the panel.