# Align JLabel to left or right on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager

How do I move/align the Yellow colored `JLabel` in the `JPanel` to right AND other `JLabel` to the left?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are on topic for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to make it on topic, please do so.

Comment: `JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); panel.add(yellowLabel, BorderLayout.LINE_END); panel.add(blueLabel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);`

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511518/how-to-align-jlabel-to-the-left-of-the-jpanel. It does not answer the question asked by the OP who want one label on the left and the other on the right.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" answers when you get help by clicking on the checkbox so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

You use an appropriate layout manager.

One option is to use a panel with a horizontal `BoxLayout`:

```
Box panel = Box.createHorizontalBox();
panel.add( leftLabel );
panel.add( Box.createHorizontalGlue() );
panel.add( yellowLabel );
```

Another option is to use a panel with a `BorderLayout`:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
panel.add(leftLabel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
panel.add(yellowLabel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Mangers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: perfect, that does it